# Inheriting to implementing ctrl hot keys

Tags: c#, inheritance

I don't know if this is "a thing", but I'm hoping. I am extending a Windows application and the user wants to be able to use the same ctrl+ combinations as Internet Explorer (ctrl+C for copy, ctrl+P for print, etc.). I'm hoping I can inherit this behavior from something already in the .NET world, but I can't find it. So if someone knows where that would be that would be great.

If not, then it looks like I'll have to add an eventhandler to handle the hot key presses and code them. And that seems like a lot of work that should have already been done somewhere. So if someone has some suggestions on where to find this sort of thing, that would be great (slightly less great, but great non-the-less).

Comment: What kind of control do you need to cut/copy from?  Are you using WPF?

Comment: ctrl+C/ctrl+V/Ctrl+Z are often inherent, depending on the control you're in, however, normally these are just expected short cuts you'll add to your menu....   But then what exactly are you working with here, console app? web app aka asp.ent? silverlight? wpf? winforms?

Comment: I'm too lazy for a real answer right now, but if you are using WPF, this might be a good point to read up on it: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/